# Generic XML file validator against XML schema (XSD file)

Tags: java, xml, generics, xsd, jaxb

I want to create a generic xmlFileValidator with JAXB, that takes a XML file and a schema file, and returns root class's object if the file is valid else throws SAXException or JAXBException.

```
public class XmlValidateEventHandler implements ValidationEventHandler {
public static <E> void validator(File xsdFile, File xmlFile, E obj) throws SAXException, JAXBException
{
    JAXBContext jaxbcontextobj = JaxbUtil.create_context_obj(new ObjectFactory());
    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = sf.newSchema(xsdFile);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JaxbUtil.create_unmarshl_obj(jaxbcontextobj);

    unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
    unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new XmlValidateEventHandler());        
    javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<Document>  doc = (javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<Document>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
    Document d = doc.getValue();
    obj=(E)d;
}

@Override
public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {

    Logger logger = utility.JaxbUtil.getLogger();
    if(event.getSeverity() == ValidationEvent.ERROR || event.getSeverity() == ValidationEvent.FATAL_ERROR)
    {                           
        //Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(XmlValidateEventHandler.class);              
        logger.error("SEVERITY:  " + event.getSeverity());          
        logger.error("MESSAGE:  " + event.getMessage());            
        logger.error("LINKED EXCEPTION:  " + event.getLinkedException());           
        logger.error("LINE NUMBER:  " + event.getLocator().getLineNumber());
        logger.error("COLUMN NUMBER:  " + event.getLocator().getColumnNumber());
        logger.error("***** Give XML is invalid aginst given XSD *****");
        return false;
    }   
}
```

}

The following line gives warning ->

> Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to JAXBElement

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<Document>  doc=(javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<Document>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
```

And I am also not able to map the unmarshaled object and set it to *E obj* which is passed in argument.
I know it can returned, but i have been asked to set it into that parameter.
Please help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I changed to following and it works :

```
    public static <E> E validator(File xsdFile, File xmlFile, E obj) throws SAXException, JAXBException
{   
    JAXBContext jaxbcontextobj = JaxbUtil.setContextObj(new ObjectFactory());
    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = sf.newSchema(xsdFile);
    Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JaxbUtil.setUnmarshlObj(jaxbcontextobj);

    unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
    unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new XmlValidateEventHandler());        
    javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<E>  doc = (javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<E>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlFile);
    E d = (E) doc.getValue();
    return d;
}
```

But now there are still open ends :
1. I am still not able not able to map the object to third parameter -> *E obj*
2. I am using ObjectFactory from JAXB generated classes :

> import XmlClasses.ObjectFactory;

Which is still making it not fully generic, how to take a generic ObjectFactory ??